# Error not displaying

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml format:

```
<searches> 

<search>
<name> stephen </name>
<address> box 23 </address>
<sector> IT </sector>
<contacts>+233247764939 </contacts>

<search>
<name> stephen </name>
<address> box 23 </address>
<sector> IT </sector>
<contacts>+233247764939 </contacts>

<searches>
```

When the value for the name node is not found I will like to display the error to the user.
I have tried using the code below but it seems the echo statement is not executing hence when the name node value is empty or does not contain a value an empty screen shows without the echo message. Any help with this code?
NB: if the name has no value then it means the company does not exist. 
this code returns a value to $objj to the next php script.

Below is the complete code:

```
<?php 
function processing($term){
$params = array ('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password', 'term'=> $term); 
// Build Http query using params
$query = http_build_query ($params);
// Create Http context details
$contextData = array (
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
"Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
'content'=> $query );
// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
print_r($context);
// Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$result =  file_get_contents (
'http://infolinetest.nandiclient.com/search/searches/requestData.xml',  // page url
false,
$context);
// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it

$obj = @simplexml_load_string($result);

 return $obj
 }
 ?>


//the outputting is done in this script

<?php  $objj = processing ($term); ?>
<div data-role="listview">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-    listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
<a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="g" data-inset="true"><strong>Search     Results</strong></a>
<?php if ($objj){    ?>        
<?php foreach(@$objj as $searches):?>
<li> <a href="Result_Selected.php?company=<?php echo $searches ->     name.'<br/>'.$searches->sector.'<br/>'.$searches ->address.'<br/>'.$searches ->     contacts.'<br/>'; ?>" data-role="button"><?php echo( $searches -> name).'<br/>'.$searches -    > sector ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
<a data-ajax="false" href="#top" data-role="button"  name= "smt"><strong>End Of List...    </strong></a>

<?php } else if(empty($objj)||($objj==null)||($objj->name=="")){    ?>

<?php  echo "hello company not found.try again"; } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: why the supressors on load string and foreach ?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error and would not work at all: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH, expecting ',' or ';'` You're missing a semicolon before the `endforeach` and you cannot mix brace style with `endforeach` style like you do. My guess is you're not posting the _actual_ code you're using.

Comment: Please [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) your code for readability. Code editors/IDEs should have an auto-indent capability, even for [HTML and XML](http://www.riedquat.de/prog/style#d1122e210) indentation. Check online style guides (such as the [Google Code style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#HTML_Formatting_Rules)) for possible guidelines and pick one to follow.

Comment: i think you need a `</searches>`as well